# Function is not found Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

I want to create a function that creates an absence for the student. If he have 3 absences he will get eliminated. But after I created the function, when I run it, it tells me it's not found.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_abbssence(
 )
    RETURNS TABLE(  etudiant int , id_matiere int, abssance int) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

 begin
  return query
 select *   from abssance  order by id_abssance;
        insert into id_abssance (id_etudiant,id_matiere,abssance)
        values (etudiant,matiere ,abssance);
        if abssane = 3 then
            insert into abssance(eliminé)
            values(1);
            --if successful 


            --isnt there 
            end if ;

 end
 $BODY$;
```

and when i run it it tells me

```
add_abbssence (integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select * from add_abbssence (66,1,1)
                      ^
HINT: No function corresponds to the given name and to the types of arguments.
You need to add explicit type conversions.
```

Answer (score 1):

The declared function has zero parameter but in your SELECT statement you have 3 parameters for the function call: this is the reason why PostgreSQL does not call the function: the function call number and types of parameters must match the function definition.

Working example for the new function code:

```
    create table abssence(id_etudiant int, id_matiere int, abssance int, éliminé int);
    CREATE TABLE

    create or replace function test1(etudiant int, matiere int, abssancee int) 
    RETURNs int as 
    $$ 
    begin 
     insert into abssence(id_etudiant,id_matiere,abssance) values(etudiant,matiere,abssancee); 
    if abssancee=3  
    then 
      insert into abssence(éliminé) values(1); 
      return 1;
    else 
     return 0; 
    end if; 
    end $$ 
    language plpgsql;
    CREATE FUNCTION

    select * from test1(1,2,3);
     test1 
    -------
         1
    (1 row)
```

Comment: after i aded the statemnts it's tells me '''
the result type of the function must be specified

Comment: i change it like this `````Create or replace function test1(etudiant int ,matiere int ,abssancee int)
RETURNs int as $$
begin 
 insert into  abssence(id_etudiant,id_matiere,abssance)
  values(etudiant,matiere,abssancee);
  if abssance=3 then
  insert into abssence(eliminé)
  values(1);
  
  else
  return 0;
  end if;
  end
  $$
  language plpgsql```````

Comment: See my updated answer: the code works but I'm not sure it is correct. If you want to write the flag `éliminé` for an existing row you should use `UPDATE` statement instead of `INSERT`.